# I need to write mysql query using case statements

Tags: mysql, case

This time I need a Big help. I need to write a mysql query to join two tables as well the query should have some case statements. I'm not an expert in mysql queries so I can't even think about this to write. so I make a diagram if someone can please give  me some help.

thank you very much.
[image]

I tried using this query. but this is not even coming closer to achieve this requirement.

```
$this->db->select('user.emp_servicing_dep,user.emp_department,user.emp_name,user.emp_applied_date,user.emp_applied_time,user.hod_apprvd_time,user.hr_apprvd_time,user.emp_servicing_brnch'
                . ',user.emp_pending_on,user.emp_status,Management.Br_no,Management.Br_name,Management.Contact_no,Management.user_name,Management.Hd_working_day,Management.Department');
        $this->db->order_by("emp_timestamp", "ASC");
        $this->db->limit(10);
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->join('Management', 'user.emp_pending_on  = Management.Department', 'left');
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure, Stack Overflow community can help on what you have tried. Please share the query that you have created and what issues are you facing in it.

Comment: @AzizShaikh -  I put the query, That I have tried to my question now. but that query never doing the thing that i needed. :(
Thank You.

Comment: Please also add your table structures, sample data, and expected results.

Comment: @AzizShaikh - Mr.Aziz, I uploaded two screen shots of my sql table.